# How to find the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I have a homework problem to find the maximal ideals in $\Bbb{Z}_8$, $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$, $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$, and $\Bbb{Z}_n$. That question has already been asked on here, but I don't even understand how to find just plain ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: They are all of the form $n\Bbb Z$. To prove it, take $n=$ the smallest positive element of an ideal and prove both inclusions. One is trivial. The other is done using Euclidean division.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the canonical map $\pi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_n$. This is a surjective  ring homomorphism and so the ideals of $\mathbb Z_n$ correspond to the ideals of $\mathbb Z$ that contain $\ker \pi= n\mathbb Z$.

All ideals of $\mathbb Z$ are of the form $m\mathbb Z$. (Because ideal and subgroup is the same for $\mathbb Z$.)

Finally, $m\mathbb Z$ contains $n\mathbb Z$ iff ...

Comment: So would this mean then that the maximal ideal for $\Bbb{Z}_8$ would be $8\Bbb{Z}$?